# Grep character sequence

Tags: java, regex

I need to match character sequences of the form `ABCD12345` and others of the form `ABCD54321.aaa`.

I have written code to check for both forms, but it only works correctly for input sequence `ABCD12345` because `ABCD54321.aaa` is matched by both RegEx's (the one for `ABCD54321.aaa` and the one for `ABCD54321`).

How do I modify my regular expression(s) so that only one of them matches when the input is `ABCD54321.aaa`?

Here is a snippet of my java code which shows the patterns that I am using to match character sequences:

```
String[] patternValues = new String[] { "[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+\\.+[a-zA-Z]{3}","[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+"} ;
for(int i = 0 ; i <= (patternValues.length - 1) ; i++) {
    Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(patternValues[i]);
    ..... 
}
```

Comment: Could you show your regular expression so that we know what to modify?

Comment: You need to show your regular expression. For all we know you could just be using "ABCD12345".

Comment: Do you really need `java` tag?

Comment: @rook Yes, some regex features are language-dependent.

Comment: My impression is that the OP is using the word "grep" for "RegEx", but we need his confirmation.  Can you please specify what tool(s) are you using and replace "grep" with "RegEx" if indicated?

Comment: Here is a snippet of my java code which shows the patterns that I am using to grep character sequence:

String[] patternValues = new String[] {"[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+\\.+[a-zA-Z]{3}","[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+"}

for (int i = 0; i <= (patternValues.length - 1); i++)
{
 Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(patternValues[i]); 
        .....

Comment: Use Pattern.compile with the Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE flag to remove all that case-insensitive garbage.

Comment: (By the way, I believe you have a stray `.` in `[Aa.]`)

Comment: @arshajii, yes I know, but author didn't provide much specific details initially, and word `grep` in the topic confused a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this regular expression for the `ABCD54321`-only match:

```
ABCD54321(?!\.aaa)
```

That will match `ABCD54321` not followed by `.aaa`.

If you want it to be case-insensitive, first prepare it with [`Pattern.compile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) using the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag:

```
Pattern.compile("abcd54321(?!\\.aaa)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. This way, I can just modify the array and not worry about special handling. the Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE will also make my life easier

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java, and that you have 2 different RegEx's checked in sequence through `aMatcher.matches()`, you can add a negative lookahead to the RegEx that is meant to match "ABCD12345" **only** (and not "ABCD54321.aaa"), namely `"[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}(?!\\.[a-z]{3})"`.  `"(?!\\.[a-z]{3})"` is the negative lookahead.

A second alternative is to keep only one RegEx (the one that matches both), retrieve the matched text (through `aMatcher.group()`) and decide from `aMatcher.group().length()` (which should be either 9 or 13).

If you prefer to use `aString.matches(aRegEx)`, then the only option is the first.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I see that both methods will work and I will choose the former since it is easier for me to to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
String[] patternValues = 
  new String[] {"[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+\\.+[a-zA-Z]{3}", "[Aa.][Bb][Cc][Dd]\\d+"};
```

Change this to:

```
String[] patternValues = 
  new String[] {"(?i)^abcd\\d+\\.+[a-z]{3}$", "(?i)^abcd\\d+$"};
```

Important changes are:

```
?i      => Ignore case match
^ and $ => line start and line end
```

Comment: How did you guess what code the OP has, that the strings to match are in individual lines, and that matching should be case-insensitive? I'm really, really curious. If they are just assumptions, then IMO it's more helpful to say so.

Comment: @MarioRossi: OP posted this code in a comment under question.

Comment: Sorry for that. The OP should have edited the question. Next time I'll check hidden comments before posting something like that. Sorry again.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! I will make the change suggested so that my code is easier to maintain!